# Use Thunderbird only to download messages with No up -sync to the Server

Tags: thunderbird, network-shares

I am trying to have ThunderBird setup in such a way that it can be used in read only mode. I am planing to set it up in a shared server and share the Mail messages with multiple users...

I want to prevent shared users from accidentally archiving /delete folders or email.

Is there anyway I could restrict users from doing that in Thunderbird.

PS:
I am using IMAP.
But, whenever I delete an email or move folders, it is also replicating in the Server.
I do not want that to happen/ prevent user from doing that even locally.

Comment: Use the IMAP instead of POP protocol for e-mail retrieval. TB works with either and IMAP was designed for exactly the use you describe.

Answer (score 0):

The authenticated user is able to do what is he allowed to do. So the solution can be to define multiple accounts for a mailbox (for different users) on you IMAP server and set ACLs on the folders and emails. Part of ACLs can be changed directly from Thunderbird using a [plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/imap-acl-extension/).